# Blazor Client WASM Client with OIDC Authentication (Google OAuth) - backed by ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to implement a Blazor WASM Client Project with ASP.NET Web API as the backend.

I have Google Authentication setup on the WASM project using:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
})
```

This allows me to get the authenticated user in my Client application.

But post-Google authentication - I want to fetch additional user details and role from the Web API but I am not getting the right steps or guides for this.

What I would like to do is:

Once Google Authentication is successful - send the Google JWT to the Web-API for server-side authentication and fetch user details and role information from the API.

Comment: As an update. I found the below code which allows me to trigger a request to my API after Google Sign-in.

.AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();

But I am not getting the id_token.

I tried AddHttpMessageHandler but still not getting the id_token

Comment: Maybe is too late, but you need to add `"token id_token"` to the ResponseType config or `options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType`